# XSLT template match with mode attribute set doesn't work

Tags: templates, xslt, match, mode

Pretty new to xslt and I am attempting to write an xslt template for PDF generation purposes.

Here is a snippet of the incoming xml:

```
<element name="rootElement">
    <attributes />
    <elements>
        <element name="childElement">
            <attributes>
                <attribute name="attributename" value="Yes" />
            </attributes>
        </element>
    </elements>
</element>
```

I need to display text specific to each child element in addition to printing all the element names and corresponding values in a tabular form.

After doing some research I thought this could be achieved with a combination of template match along with setting the mode attribute. Here is the code I wrote:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:template match="DOCUMENT">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DATA" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATA">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="element" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="element" mode="test" />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element">
        <fo:block font-size="18.0pt" font-family="Arial"
            font-weight="bold">
            Display something I.
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element" mode="test">
        <fo:block font-size="18.0pt" font-family="Arial"
            font-weight="bold">
            Display something II.
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the output after execution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-size="18.0pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold">
            Display something I.
</fo:block>
```

Can anyone please tell me why the template match with mode didn't execute?

Any thoughts/solutions/insights will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need an `apply-templates` somewhere in the `element` template to continue the processing down the node tree, but what is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your response - I was hoping for the element template with the mode attribute to be invoked and print out the xml containing the text Display Something II in addition to the standard element template match contents.

Comment: Your current XSLT is looking for the elements **DOCUMENT** and **DATA**, which are not present at all in your XML. Is your XML sample definitely correct?

Comment: @user2624928, the `<xsl:apply-templates select="element" mode="test" />` is done inside of a `template match="DATA"`, yet the input sample you have posted does not show any elements of that name. So why do you expect that apply-templates `mode="test"` to be called? If you continue to have problems then consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing others to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user2624928 Instead of explaining to us what you want the result to look like, please show us what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no DATA element, it must be that the match="element" template is being invoked from the default built-in template, which doesn't do an apply-templates with mode="test".

Answer (score 0):

Neither `<xsl:template match="DOCUMENT">` nor `<xsl:template match="DATA">` get executed.

If you change thee second template to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="element" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element" mode="test" />

</xsl:template>
```

you should see your expected results.